# how to convert a timestamp to 28 Dec, 2018 like format in php?

Tags: php

I am a Beginner in Web Development. I have used the `data type timestamp` for the `date` in the database. Now I want to show the date in this format like `28 Dec 2018` but I don't know how to do that. please tell me how to convert it in php?

[image: TimeStamp Database Picture]

Comment: Please use [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/function.date.php) function. In your case, you should use it like this `date('j M Y', $yourTimeStamp);`

Comment: You can do this :  $formatted_date =  date('j M Y', strtotime($db_date));. 
Thank you.

Comment: it gives me an error "A non well formed numeric value encountered in E:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommerce_SimplePHP\blog-detail.php on line 53".
and this is my code "<?php
                                        $row1 = $row['date'];
                                       echo date('j M Y', $row1); ?>"